# How to print out Spark connection of Spark session ?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I run `pyspark` command and got global variable `spark` of type `SparkSession`. As I understand, this `spark` holds a connection to the Spark master. Can I print out the details of this connection including the hostname of this Spark master ?

Comment: `spark.sparkContext.master` would be a good start. You'll need some additional logic for `local` and YARN to get actual host.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that `spark.sparkContext.master` is `yarn` in my case. Do you how to get the master hostname ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For basic information you can use `master` property:

```
spark.sparkContext.master
```

To get details on YARN you might have to dig through `hadoopConfiguration`:

```
hadoopConfiguration = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConfiguration.get("yarn.resourcemanager.hostname")
```

or

```
hadoopConfiguration.get("yarn.resourcemanager.address")
```

When submitted to YARN Spark uses Hadoop configuration to determine the resource manger so these values should match ones present in configuration placed in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question: what does it mean if `"yarn.resourcemanager.hostname"` is `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Looks like your local machine (do you run YARN on the same node?).